# Is there a way to loop query builder through orWhereIn parameters one by one?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if there's a way to loop `->OrWhereIn('parent_id', $data1,2,3,4,5)`?

```
 $data= data::query()
    ->where('parent_id', $this->id)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $data1)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $data2)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $data3)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $data4);
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses): `->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])` (Applies to whereIn / whereNotIn / orWhereIn / orWhereNotIn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `whereIn` function to achieve that result and instead of looping queries, just loop the array you pass `whereIn` function as second parameter.

```
$parent_ids = [];

foreach($some_data as $data) {
  // [add ids in parent_ids here]
}

$data= data::query()->whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids);
```

Or if you want to loop in query builder you can use nested where:

```
$parent_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, $data];

$data= data::query()
    ->where(function($q) use ($parent_ids) {
      foreach($parent_ids as $id) {
        $q->orWhere('parent_id', $id);
      }
    });
```

Result SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (parent_id = 1 OR parent_id = 2 OR parent_id = 3 ... );
```

Comment: I **highly** recommend to use first solution. because of performance standpoint

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could something like this:

```
->orWhereIn('parent_id', [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4])
```

Provided all of these are not subarrays. If they are merge them into a single array before trying this.